# export tables of mysql database for insertion into a different database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a wordpress instance running on my localhost. In order to move this to another server, I'd like to export the contents of this database to an sql file. However, I don't have the permission to create new databases, I have an existing database in which I'd like to insert the tables and all the rows inside them. Is there a way to tell phpmyadmin to export the data in such a way that everything will be inserted into this new database? Or would it be better to just do a find/replace inside the sql file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, if you select the database in phpmyadmin, it shows all the tables contained. If you choose to export at that stage, it will export by default (actually depends on its version) all the tables structure and data without database creation. Additionally, it does give you the option of exporting only the data.